# Spring access page only when session exists

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

It is possible to set up @RequestMapping annotation to only allow viewing a page if a session exists? (The user is logged on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use spring-security for some reason and want to have your custom implementation to allow access only is session exists, then you could also write a RequestFilter that implements javax.servlet.Filter, and check if the request has a valid session then allow it to go through else show an error page. Here's an example.

```
public class RequestAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RequestAuthenticationFilter.class);

    protected static final List<String> ALLOWED_URL_LIST = Arrays.asList("/login.htm", "/400.htm", "/403.htm", "/404.htm", "/405.htm", "/500.htm", "/503.htm");

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String url = (request.getRequestURI());

        if(ALLOWED_URL_LIST.contains(url) || url.endsWith(".css") || url.endsWith(".js") || url.endsWith(".png")
            || url.endsWith(".jpg") || url.endsWith(".jpeg") || url.endsWith(".ttf") || url.endsWith(".woff")
            || url.endsWith(".csv")) {

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else if((null == session) || session.getAttribute("user") == null
            || StringUtils.isEmpty(((User) session.getAttribute("user")).getUsername().trim())) {

            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("/login.htm");
        }
        else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

In this example the additional check is that if the request is for any image,js,css file then we skip the session check.

Once you have added the filter implementation, you will have to next make sure that all the requests that you want to validate with session go through this Filter. For that you will have to create a bean for this filter and then reference that bean in your web.xml

Here's what you will have to include in your web.xml. Here the  is the name with which you create the bean for your filter. And the  can be used for deciding which url's you want verified for session check with this filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>requestAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up through [Spring-Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) fairly easily - for eg. consider a sample configuration from Spring-security site:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_DBA')")  
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
            .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
}
```

here paths mapped with `/resources` is allowed for everybody(including anonymous users), everything else requires the user to have some role or atleast to have logged in.